Term of art for ontological evasion
I am looking for a term that I would call ontological evasion (or ontlogical elision if we wish to sound more neutral) but I dont find anything like it in the standard places — IEP/SEP/wikipedia.
The context
This is in the technical computer science (CS) context of semantics of programming languages [Not remotely political!]
The question arises in certain high level languages in the context of semantics of memory. Lower level languages like C explicitly have a concept (ontology) called pointer, dereferencing it yields a piece of memory.
Languages that lay claim to be more high level do not have a concept of pointer but they still need to have (a model for) memory and so the pointer which is simply a pre-reification of memory willy-nilly gets into the meta-level semantics even if its elided in the manual, ie. the object level.
This (looooong) thread on the Python mailing list displays the dispute:

Marko: Everything in Python evaluates to a pointer
Chris: Python has no such thing as pointer

Some further notes

C++ has the situation reified within the language:

frank pointers as in C are called, well pointers!
elided pointers are called references
there are all sorts of others like smart pointers, member pointers etc


So different languages (try to) do these things differently with Python avoiding the ontology and C++ making fine distinctions, and so on.  While the question here is not regarding fine CS distinctions, some other nearby generic terms (I can come up with!) are
reference, address, handle, descriptor, indirection, alias, link, proxy.
Mentioning the list of alternate terms above because reference and reification — sometimes called first-class in CS — are terms of art in philosophy and are vaguely related to pointer, and dereferencing.

Addendum 1

For those claiming this to be inappropriate to this site since its about programming, here is George Carlin describing evasion without any CS stuff. It comes quite close to what I am looking for except that I want a description for Fine talking of X; avoid talking of Y; even though X-Y are inseparable.
Also I'd rather stay away from a political flavor
Conversely, for those giving computer-sciency answers, see here. It demonstrates that both memory and pointers are inextricably linked to the issue.
Also this is not specifically about Python. Java, Ruby, Javascript etc., all have the same issue with small variations in terminology.

Addendum 2 — Reformulation
Thanks to the comments below it occured to me I could reforulate the question more positively. Instead of 'trick', 'evasion' etc., lets talk of...
The Jigsaw Effect

A completed jigsaw is a completed jigsaw.
More significantly, an incomplete jigsaw is not a completed jigsaw, even if one piece of of 200 is removed

Some standard egs from philosophy (no relation of CS!)
The Semiotic Ontology
Compare

Saussure offered a 'dyadic' or two-part model of the sign. He defined a sign as being composed of:

a 'signifier' (signifiant) - the form which the sign takes; and
the 'signified' (signified) - the concept it represents.


with

For Peirce, then, any instance of signification contains a (1) sign-vehicle, (2) an object and (3) interpretant.  This triadic structure... is present in all of Pierce's accounts.

The fact that we talk of Sassurean and Piercean semiotics means they are different!
Essential Christianity
The Nicene Creed runs:

I believe in One God, the Father almight...
I believe in One Lord, Jesus Christ, the Only begotten Son of God,
I believe in  the Holy Spirit, the Lord, the giver of life... who has spoken through the prophets...

Now say a person says Christ the Son is enough for me; I dont need Father — I am an atheist — and whoever runs after ghosts, holy or otherwise!
Would he be a Christian in any reasonable sense?
Reductionism
[Tnx to Bumble]
Bumble: ...we can account for language about objects at one level in terms of language about objects at a lower level...
Answer: And we can do that reductionism improperly with category errors eg Saying Everything is {Hydrogen, Helium... Plutonium, Californium} is ok; Saying Everything is {electrons, protons, neutrons} is ok — another level. But what if we say Everything is electrons protons and hydrogen?
This wrong way of building ontologies is what I want a term for.
For now and for this forum we can put aside memory/pointers and CS questions in general

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"Term of art for ontological evasion" You never explain what "ontological evasion" means. The "context" does not clarify, it's not clear what "the dispute" is or what it has to do with "ontological evasion" & the addendums do not clarify or "reformulate the question" (etc etc). Also this a big ramble. Please read what this post actually says & more importantly doesn't say & doesn't need to say & edit to clarify & focus.

The CS terms you use have vague generic meanings & specific meanings in certain contexts/languages. Moreover almost all you say about specific languages is wrong/misconceived. Please use as few technical terms as possible & define them & use simple language & minimal specific examples & say what you think is going on in each example. Similarly the philosophical terms you use are general & referencing does not help to explain what you haven't clearly written; one would have to know what you are talking about in the 1st place in order to argue that such terms could reasonably be applied & why.

This technique is called abstraction in computer science. We say that the programming language implements an abstraction on top of the hardware, and that the abstraction is a higher-level language.
You seem to be equivocating between the abstraction and the implementation. C++ references and Python objects may be implemented in terms of pointers but in terms of the language abstraction they are not pointers. Language values may be implemented by storing a representation of them in computer memory, but the computer memory itself is not part of the language abstraction (at least it is understood at the assembly-language level; C++ does support the notion of chunks of memory that other objects can be implemented in).
When someone says that Python does not have pointers, they are talking about the language abstraction. If they were talking about the implementation--how the language abstraction is realized on hardware--then this would be surprising (not impossible, though). But as far as that goes, even pointers are an abstraction. At the level of assembly language, there are only integers which can be used to index into RAM. But even that is an abstraction. At the machine architecture level, there are only bits laid out in arrays that can be interpreted as integers. But even that is an abstraction. At the logic level there are only gates and other logic circuits. But even that is an abstraction. At the electronics level, there are only transistors and other circuit elements. But even that is an abstraction...
As you can see, pointers are not fundamental part of programming. They are just a convenient abstractions used in some programming languages for some purposes. If a language abstraction doesn't have pointers, then there is probably no value to trying to look under the hood to see pointers underneath.
ADDENDUM:
In discussion you cite, Marko seems to be using the word "pointer" when he should be using the word "reference" and this is causing confusion; the two people are talking past each other. A pointer is a first-class language object; a reference is not. A first-class object is something that you can do the usual things on just like integers and strings. There are operators that can be used on them (in non-C languages, you can at least dereference a pointer), you can pass them to functions, and return them from functions just like any other value. There is no dereference operation in Python and although you can describe what Python does as passing and returning references, it doesn't pass and return references in the same sense as it passes and returns integers and strings.

You are giving a CS-ist's answer, Tnx for that — but I want a philosopher's answer.  You can check that I have an expanded version of your penultimate paragraph here
a second answer is also relevant.
My (CSist) point is that you cant say pointers are non-fundamental and yet say memory is.  [V hlls like Haskell actually succeed in throwing out both]. I want this "sleight-of-hand" described in general/generic philosophical terms

Since you use the term abstraction in the CS sense, my response would be Spolsky's law : The abstraction leaks. You will see (if you go through the long thread I referenced) that disputants there are saying exactly what you are: A: The pointer in the underlying implementation is not relevant to the abstraction. B: You cannot talk of the language without it. So it very much is. I'm hoping a philosopher can give me a fallacy of logic/trick of rhetoric etc that describes the argument

I've added an addendum. As to the philosophical issue, there is none. No one is using a trick here; people are just talking past each other.

@Rushi, I've added an addendum. Also see my previous comment where I forgot to tag you.

No trick here Respectfully, I disagree.See for why one cannot understand Python without understanding memory refs. Now you can choose to call reified refs as pointers and unrefied as just refs. But that just amounts to using C++ as a metalanguage to describe. Nothing wrong with that (in a CS context). But in a philosophy context reference is the more reified term. The "trick" is the language spec not bringing in an ontology necessary to understand key features of the language

@Rushi, Regardless of terminology, people are talking past each other. There is no need to understand pointers --meaning references as first-class objects-- in order to understand Python. Yes, you do need to understand references to understand Python just like you need them to understand normal language and for the same reason. The example you linked to is nothing mysterious; it just shows how when you change an object you change the object for all references to it. A minor is in court. His lawyer is his father, John Smith. His lawyer and one parent are supposed to show up at the court hearing

If John Smith shows up, that satisfies the requirement. However, John Smith is mutated by having an accident that put him in the hospital, so he can't show up. The minor's father was injured and this made it impossible for his lawyer to make it to the hearing as well as his father. Python works just the same.

Yeah ok but here its more of a halloween party where no one knows who's who behind the mask. Alternate example

@Rushi, as to the ontology of computer languages, you might find this interesting: http://www.unobtainabol.com/2014/09/identity-ontology-and-pass-by-value.html

Seems worth a study — tnx

The only difference there is between those who know what there is to know, the technical meaning of those terms to begin with, and those who just don't and can't even tell that they don't: and, in that, it is a perfect example, of the "misery of an entire industry".  That said, you had presented the question as not political, but the more you expand on it, the less I can even guess what you are after.

@JulioDiEgidio, in defense of those who use "pointer" and "reference" interchangeably, it's the sort of thing that happens in language all the time. Pointers and references do have a lot in common, and if you are focusing on what they have in common, it is easy to miss the differences.

@DavidGudeman I have not said "references" anywhere! Anyway, for the chronicle, I'd complain about conflating pointers with references not any less than I'd complain about conflating "pointers" with "data". Though, of course, the former mistake is not as dramatic as the latter. -- I am really not interested in the details of that discussion, the discipline is missing! And I am talking about an entire industry. E.g. "by my book", reference is slightly above pointer in terms of levels of abstraction, still very concrete: and that's all there is to it, at least as far as what is what.  (EOD.)

Your blog post above is the closest I see so far to the answer I am looking for. Expand it and I'll accept. Of course that will disagree with this answer  Problem is not about abstractions — right or wrong — but about something more 'prior'. What Ive called, for want of knowing anything better, a broken ontology

@Rushi, what do you want me to expand?

I guess what I would accept is not an expansion of this answer but a contraction of your blog post. Maybe another answer..?? (Sorry, the "expand" above has the wrong subject)

Also note that abstraction and reduction are complementary directions (see note at end of my q to bumble). So if one is misspplied so is the other.


Languages that lay claim to be more high level do not have a concept of pointer but they still need to have (a model for) memory

I'd agree (with you: I haven't actually dug into the dispute) that, if -say- the Python language spec has "pointers", then there are "pointers" in Python, otherwise there just aren't: and mixing the language spec with the terms of a language implementation, in a dispute as in a language spec, I'd call mixing levels of abstractions, itself maybe an instance of categorical errors.
Along that line, I find incorrect that "high level [languages] still need to have (a model for) memory": the high(er)-level concept exists and is "data".

Your point about data is very correct. +1 As Codd outlined, a data model is not properly mathematical (he called it relational) if it didn't meet some desiderata. The eighth rule is about the requirement to be independent of physical representation.

As for para 2, I must repectfully disagree. Language designers/implementors happen to be human beings. They can make mistakes (I should know, I'm one of   them Because an implementation is itself a program, one category of errors are the usual bugs programmers make. The other category are design errors.

If "term" is there in the spec it's there in the language. If it's not it's not. (my paraphrase). My question is fundamentally about this: What if the term is absent but the concept unavoidable?

"What if the term is absent but the concept unavoidable?"  (IMO) there is no such thing: "leaky abstractions" I think you have called them, and I do think that's all those are.

Ok but I was hoping for a more generic (older than Spolsky!!) philosophical term

Don't invoke philosophy in vain. :)  "Mixing levels of abstraction" is, AFAICT, what that is.

Well I used to have a smoking gun but I've misplaced it... there was reference to address in version n which disappeared in n + 1. I don't want to go there because it becomes orwellian — newspeak — but we are living in such inflammatory times I'd rather avoid that line . By n large I like to stick to Hanlons razor: They know not...

I think... thanks to these discussions I have a clearer,more positive formulation of the question. I'll add/edit it in after I wake up

You state that pointers are references in memory, than all memory can be pointers. Higher level languages claim to not use pointers but that seems impossible because it has to use memory. It can't create anything that references itself outside of itself.
This is called self-deception: one convinces oneself there is no need for references/pointers only to make a claim for a higher level of abstraction.
This IS an ontological argument in itself, using an analogy would make it clearer that it is an ontological claim: Someone wants to believe that there is something outside of reality/existence. So they deceive themselves that references to reality can be made that do not come from reality/existence despite the fact that for something to make a reference it has to exist.

This question is about ontology not CS. Please see reformulation at the end of the question

@Rushi I'm using your CS example to explain the ontological argument that you are trying to make which I believe is panpsychism. So my answer isn't about CS it's about ontology and I think the example you illustrate takes a panpsychist's stance.

@Rushi My phrasing of my answer is wrong. I should have said that if you state that pointers are references in memory, than all memory can be pointers. Higher level languages claim to not use pointers but that seems impossible because it has to use memory. It can't create anything that references itself outside of itself.

Um... The last comment is better than your answer

@Rushi I agree. You aren't claiming Panpsychism because you don't assume that everything is a pointer simply that everything CAN be a pointer. I think the phrase you are looking for is self-deception. I edited my answer. I hope you find it satisfactory.

Your second (short) para reads very garbled. Can you reword it (something like) this please?  : This is called self-deception: one convinces oneself there is no need for references/pointers only to make a claim for a higher level of abstraction.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I feel the example given here is one of semantics rather than anything dealing with ontology.  This is true about many debates.  It is possible to argue for either side on the example depending on ones definition of pointer.  For example wikipedia starts with the definition pointers as:
a pointer is an object in many programming languages that stores a memory address.
I would argue that python does not have such an object.  Everyone agrees with the underlying existence of memory to hold data so ontologically there is no disagreement.
The idea of ontological evasion would come about with such things as the existence of god.
Another term would be ontological skepticism.
Addendum: Thinking on this more a local variable b=3 also references memory and I do not consider it a pointers, so I can state: According to my current definition of pointer (similar to wikipedia) python doesn't have pointers.

There are two good answers so far, but you've asked for a philosophical bent to it.  I'd invoke a Nietzsche quote to question your use of ontology:

"Truths are illusions we have forgotten are illusions."

You are arguing that all of these "higher level" concepts like references are things people claim are true, but you see them as illusions, built on top of pointers.
Need I remind you that a pointer is an illusion on top of bytes?  In the end, the difference between a pointer and a 32 or 64 bit number is merely that a pointer appears at the root of an indirect memory access opcode like mov (eax), ecx.  And those illusions of bytes are really just voltages constructed from conglomerations of charges on small isolates sections of silicon.
Other answers have suggested the word you look for is "abstraction" and I agree.  All we are talking about here are patterns which can be implemented in many ways.  In the case of references/smart-pointers/etc., one way to implement them is with pointers.  But there's no reason to believe that is the only way.
Indeed, if you look at the C++ spec, you will find shared_ptr carefully speaks around some of these topics.  It talks of "owning" data, without referring to the underlying ref-counting techniques that are used by basically every implementation in existence.

Pls see my reformulation. I can add more details on the CS facet.  But I really want to concentrate on the ontology facet

You are arguing that all of these "higher level" concepts like references are things people claim are true, but you see them as illusions, built on top of pointers Thats not what I am claiming. I am claiming that pointers (addresses/references/...) and memory are the same level. You can have both or elide both. Pure data in the RDBMS sense is memory reference and location agnostic. See Coods rules

The problem with those "higher level" concepts is not that they are illusions, the problem is that they are pointers in disguise. I.e. they function as pointers, they behave as pointers, for all intents and purposes they are pointers, but don't you ever dare to call them pointers!

@Rushi In my mind, the high-level meaning of 'pointer' is "something that points".  IMO, a FK in a RDMBS is a pointer at that level.  In other words, a C-pointer is simply concrete implementation of the high-level concept of 'pointer' just like a 'chef's knife' and a 'putty knife' are both knives even though they are very different in form and use. The problem with 'pointer' here is that people get all Crocodile Dundee about it: "that's not a knife, this is a knife"

@cmaster-reinstatemonica: What is the difference between a disguise and an illusion?

@Kevin An illusion is something that seems to be there, but is not. It is not real. A disguise, however, is very real. It just conceals the true nature of something. A fata morgana is an illusion, a bankster is a crook in disguise.

@Rushi There are things I can do to pointers which I cannot do to references (in particular, arbitrary addition and subtraction operations).  There are things I can do with references that I cannot do with pointers (make many very useful provable statements about the behaviors of the system).  You can say that they are on the same level, and not be wrong.  But we will have to be careful about how much "being on the same level" equates the two or even makes them meaningfully similar.  Handwaving their differences too much can lead to uncomfortable statements about them.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica We could debate illusion vs disguise if we wanted.  I might even agree in the end.  I readily admit to choosing the words that fit with a historical philosopher's quote.  I feel the wider-reaching implications of his quote are rather useful, and I choose to invoke it.

@CortAmmon Reminder: This a philosophy forum and I didn't forget when I asked. If I change my hat [I've been a programming teacher for near 4 decades] I would say mostly everything your comment saying. As a philosopher l— 50k ft view — this is just shoehorning C++ ideas as your metalanguage. C++ has both C has only pointers Haskell hasneither . And OOP languages (Java) have only references

@Rushi The philosophical argument I might make is that, while looking for a word with a meaning close to what you term "ontological evasion" or "ontological elision" might find its end in the possibility that the ontology one speaks of is an illusion.  In that case, the quoted terms you use take on a rather interesting twist.  The answer you seek may only exist if one assumes a particular ontology.

I want to prove the OOP choice inconsistent.  The proof needs to be a CSists, the framework for the proof needs be logicsl/philosophical

THats where I sought to go with my second paragraph.  pointers may be "eliding" an "ontological" reality that they're just bytes.  There are no pointers.   And bytes may be "eliding" the reality that they're just voltages.  There are no bytes.  (and honestly, I don't mind the "there's only voltages" mindset because it lets me avoid having to care which side of a soft-boiled egg one cracks, if you're familair with that reference)

@Rushi "I want to proe the OOP choice inconsistent" Can you quickly explain to me what that choice is?  I'm not immediately seeing it in your question body (whether that's because it's not there or because I simply missed it)

2 para: I'm not saying illusion; I'm saying inconsistent. Try replacing illusion with inconsistent and the arguments (may) go to what I'm looking for

Prove oop inconsistent is heavily a CS discussion. Not fir here. Think of a quantum physicist using partial differential equations. And needing to master these prior to doing QM. My question is the PDE part. The QM part is for elsewhere

Denialist
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denialist

a person who denies the existence, truth, or validity of something despite proof or strong evidence that it is real, true, or valid

Psychosis

Psychosis refers to a collection of symptoms that affect the mind, where there has been some loss of contact with reality.

Semantic Discord
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_discord

Semantic discord is the situation where two parties disagree on the definition of a word(s) that is essential to communicating or formulating the concept(s) being discussed.

I would map the dispute over whether pointers exist or do not exist in some programming context to the category of semantic discord.

Denialist... Umm... thats close And yet too strong an emotional/political over/undertone

@Rushi One would have to develop a definition of pointer that all parties accept. Then compare that to the structures that exist or do not exist at some layer of abstraction. The resulting disagreements would map to other concepts such as psychosis, denialism, or semantic disagreement, etc. There is no one way to resolve the ontological disputes it is a product of the process of distributed human intelligence (DHI). Humans generate these disputes due to inherent limits of how we each recognize patterns, make efforts to reason, and use language. We use DHI to describe distributed AI or DAI!
